# where does this build flag come from if not in the clang command line

Tags: cmake, clang++

I have a clang build line which looks something like this:

```
bin/clang++ -Werror=foo -Wno-bar...
```

etc etc. There's basically a bunch of warning and error flags. Ok that makes sense. Then, I get an error such as:

```
error: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'ulong' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int') [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
```

Where -Wshorten-64-to-32 was not a flag in the above clang++ command. So it must be coming from somewhere outside of that line. Can clang be using flags that are outside of the command line? My understanding is that all flags that it is using would be printed on that command directly.

Answer (score 1):

Many warnings are on by default, and others are enabled by options like `-Wall`, `-Wextra`, etc, that implicitly enable multiple warning categories at once.

The warning category `-Wshorten-64-to-32` is reported so that you have a way to turn off that specific warning if you don't like it, by adding `-Wno-shorten-64-to-32` to the command line.